# Add category description after the category title in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I would like to add a short description for the category, but at the moment adding the code to "content-single-product.php" each category and subcategory has the same description. Do you have an idea how to solve this or solve it in another way?

I tried to use this code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_cat');

if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        // Check if the product belongs to this category
        if (has_term($term->term_id, 'product_cat')) {
            // Get the category description
            $category_description = term_description($term->term_id, 'product_cat');

            if (!empty($category_description)) {
                echo '<div class="category-description">';
                echo '<p>' . $category_description . '</p>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How it looks for categories and subcategories:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding templates, use first the available hooks.

The right template to be used here is: `content-product-cat.php`.

The following code will add the category description after the title as you are expecting:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', 'action_woocommerce_after_subcategory' );
function action_woocommerce_after_subcategory( $category ) {
    if ( $category_description = term_description($category->term_id) ){
        echo '<p class="cat-description">'. $category_description . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.